# Acceso a mi fichero message.properties desde javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito acceder a variables que se encuentran en mi fichero "message.properties" desde un fichero .js
Supongamos que contamos con lo siguiente:

**message.properties**

```
ERROR = La longitud máxima son 20 digitos.
```

**validacion.js**
En este fichero lo que tengo actualmente es lo siguiente:

```
  $.validator.addMethod('msis', function (value, element) {     
        var result = false, m, regex1 = /^\d{1,20}$/;

        if(regex1.test(value))
            result = true;

        return result;
    }, 'Formato invalido. ');
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría sustituir la cadena de texto que muestro actualmente "Formato invalido" por el ERROR de mi message.properties?

Comment: ¿Estás hablando de una aplicación Java? En ese caso los ficheros .properties están dentro del JAR/WAR y no son accesibles por el usuario

Comment: Buenas Pablo, gracias por tu respuesta ante todo. Si, se trata de una aplicación Java, ¿no sería posible entonces recuperar valores del .properties desde mi fichero .js en vez de hacerlo desde el HTML utilizando thymeleaf por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

No se puede acceder a los ficheros de internacionalización (i18n) desde el usuario, ya que están dentro del JAR/WAR y no se sirven.

Existen varias opciones, pero te comento una: Crear archivos de i18n para front-end accesibles, por ejemplo un fichero JSON:

**es.json**

```
{
  "errors": {
    "mailFormat": "El formato del email es inválido"
    ...
  }
}
```

**en.json**

```
{
  "errors": {
    "mailFormat": "The email format is not valid"
    ...
  }
}
```

Y obtener el fichero correcto mediante AJAX según el idioma, para entonces leer los mensajes:

```
alert(i18n.errors.mailFormat);
```

Esto es más o menos lo que hacen librerías como ngx-translate para Angular o [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) (compatible con muchos frameworks y librerías)

Comment: Estoy intentando reproducir tu ejemplo pero no me está mostrando el valor desde el fichero .js
He creado un nuevo directorio en el proyecto de nombre "i18n" y en el interior he creado el "es.json" con el mismo contenido que en tu ejemplo.
Desde mi fichero .js lo llamo como en tu ejemplo "alert(i18n.errors.mailFormat);" No he hecho nada mas, ¿habría que hacer algo aparte de esto como indicar en el .js la ruta exacta donde se encuentra el "es.json" o algo similar?

Comment: El fichero json debería estar con el resto de recursos (assets) de front end... es decir con las imágenes y el resto de ficheros JS. Tendrías que hacer una llamada AJAX para obtenerlo y guardarlo en una variable (que en mi ejemplo he llamado i18n). Entonces podrías usarlo